# Forward declaration in SML/NJ (A call B , B call A)

Tags: sml, smlnj

Consider - `fun A()` call `fun B()` and vise versa and I implement `A()` before `B()`, like this:

```
fun A() = 
  B() ; 

fun B() =
  A() ;
```

In such case the SML/NJ interpreter prompts  -

```
 Error: unbound variable or c onstructor: B
```

How do I solve this? Maybe something like *forward declaration*?

(leave it that it cause infinite loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need as such to use a let binding for this. You can declare it at top level as well:

```
fun a () = b ()    
and b () = a ()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `and` keyword to declare mutually recursive functions.

```
fun A () = B ()
and B () = A ()
```

You also use the same keyword to make mutually recursive datatypes.

Note, usually you'll write function names with the first letter in lowercase:

```
fun a () = b ()
and b () = a ()
```

This helps with distinguishing between functions and value constructors.